# Flask app showing error showing attribute error when accessing foreignkey value

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'username' . I don't know why this happening.
In this `return jsonify([{'products':c.products, "user": c.user.username} for c in cart])` `c.user.username` throws Attribute error.

Code is below

#Views

```
@app.route('/cart-all')
def show_cart():
    user = current_user
    cart = Cart.query.filter_by(user=user.id).all()
    return jsonify([{'products':c.products, "user": c.user.username} for c in cart])
```

#Models

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(length=20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(length=50), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(length=60), nullable=False)
    is_admin = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    cart = db.relationship(
        "Cart", cascade="all, delete, delete-orphan",  lazy=True
    )
```

```
class Cart(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    user = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey("user.id"), nullable=False)
    products = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey("product.id"), nullable=False)
    quantity = db.Column(db.Integer())

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Comment: c.user is an integer as, in the cart table, it's just the foreign key. When you query, Since this seems like sqlalchemy, you'll likely want to use a joinedload.

Comment: Yes its sqlalchemy. Got used to Django orm. So doesn't feels to use raw sql here. so went with sqlalachemy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is how you use and define your `user` in `Cart`.

You define it simply as an integer foreign key, so when you try to access `c.user.username` in `show_cart`'s `return`, that fails because a `int` does not have a `username` attribute.

You define the `User`'s `cart` as a `relationship`, why not have a bidirectional `relationship` ?

Then you can use `cart.user` as an instance of `User`.

```py
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(length=20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(length=50), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(length=60), nullable=False)
    is_admin = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    cart = db.relationship(
        "Cart", back_populates="user", cascade="all, delete, delete-orphan",  lazy=True
    )

class Cart(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey("user.id"), nullable=False)
    user = relationship("User", back_populates="cart")  # add kwargs you need
    products = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey("product.id"), nullable=False)  # maybe this one is a relationship as well
    quantity = db.Column(db.Integer())

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Comment: I didn't know about this "back_populates" thing